# How to automatically pull an information from a form field onto an other page?

Tags: customization, query, forms

I created a form where people fill certain informations (name, phone, email, etc.). I would like to "catch" some information (name only) from the said form, once it is submitted, and have it automatically pulled in an other page of my WordPress site.

In other terms : I want to save the person's name (coming from a form) somewhere in my database when the form is successfully submitted, and that on the page of supports, automatically pull the names from the database and display them.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think this is WordPress-specific, and your question is very broad. In short, you'd want to save the person's name somewhere in your database when the form is successfully submitted, and on your page of supports just pull the names from the database and display them.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I'm not very familiar with the english terms of coding...

But YES, what you are saying is exactly what I'm trying to do !

Comment: Your question might belong over in stackoverflow.com since it's not technically WordPress-related, or you should edit it to add more details about WordPress and how you're trying to integrate the form data with it.